# Why does apollo graphql query get triggered again on the graphql server?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I have a graphql query which triggers a long task. When this query is fired from the react app using useLazyQuery or from graphql playground it refires after some time (not visible on the network tab).

I have set a server timeout for the apollo-server-express as follows

```
import express from "express";
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import fs from "fs";
import { resolvers } from "./graphql/resolvers/resolvers.js";
import { typeDefs } from "./GraphQL/typeDefs";
const cors = require("cors");

const startServer = async () => {
  console.log("[Server] Creating Express Server");
  var dir = "src/graphql/resolvers/audiofiles";

  if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
    console.log("[Server] Creating directory ", dir);
    fs.mkdirSync(dir);
  }
  const app = express();
  app.use(cors());
  console.log("[Server] Creating ApolloServer");
  const apollo = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers
  });

  apollo.applyMiddleware({ app });

  console.log("[Server] Connecting to MongoDB");
  await mongoose
    .connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/database",
      {
        useNewUrlParser: true
      }
    )
    .then(
      app.listen(
        {
          port: 4000,
          origin: {
            requestTimeout: "1200s"
          }
        },
        () =>
          console.log(`Server ready at http://****:4000${apollo.graphqlPath}`)
      )
    )
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};

startServer();
```

I want to know whether this is a front-end issue or a server side issue and why does it behave in this way and what is a good solution to stop it?